# Animating container layers in PIXI.js

Tags: pixi.js

I'm, using Tiled map generator to generate water layers in JSON format.
then I'm looping layer by layer setting the container and adding it to another container.
this gives me a few water containers. I want to animate them by showing only one layer at a time and changing visible layer per some time.

this is how update method for water class looks:

```
update (delta) {
    this.prevDeltas += Math.round(delta);

    if (this.prevDeltas % 10 !== 1) return;

    const length = this.waterLayers.children.length;

    const visibleLayerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (length + 1));

    this.waterLayers.children.forEach((layer, index) => {
      layer.visible = visibleLayerIndex === index;
    })
  }
```

this is part of tick class (this.objects is array of objects that have update method for exmaple water)

```
runTicker(app) {
    app.ticker.add((delta) => {
      this.objects.forEach((object) => {
        object.update(delta);
      });
    });
  }
```

putting aside `if (this.prevDeltas % 10 !== 1) return;` just wanted to test it fast and it works, but is changing layer visibility good idea to animate water? Is there recomended way of animating container of containers?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to try AnimatedSprite instead:

- https://pixijs.io/examples/#/sprite/animatedsprite-explosion.js
- https://pixijs.io/examples/#/sprite/animatedsprite-animationspeed.js
- https://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.AnimatedSprite.html

Try do some research about this.

If you will have further questions then try posting there: https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/discussions/